# When I compile my Verilog code I get this message. Anybody know what is the reason?

Tags: verilog, cpu

When I compile my code I get these error msg for following lines. can someone explain it.

This is verilog code for a processor

```
assign Imm = instruction[7:0];
assign OUT1addr = instruction[2:0];
assign OUT2addr = instruction[10:8];
assign INaddr = instruction[18:16];


assign address = instruction[23:16];

assign address = instruction[7:0];
```

The following message comes for ABOVE LINES

tgt-vvp sorry: procedural continuous assignments are not yet fully supp
orted. The RHS of this assignment will only be evaluated once, at the time the assignment statement is executed.

Comment: You do not show the code surrounding this. Do you have this inside an `always...` statement? If so remove the assign. Always show us as much code as possible!

Comment: The compiler does not like the double `assign` to address.

Comment: How could i fix it?

Comment: the code was too big that why i uploaded the lines with errors

Answer (score 3):

You did not do what I asked which is show me where that code is.

From the error message I very much suspect that code is inside an always block:

```
always @( ...)
...
   assign Imm = instruction[7:0];
```

This is called "a procedural continuous assignment".

The alternative is:

```
always @( ...)
...
   Imm = instruction[7:0];
```

This is a standard assignment.

There is a significant difference between the two. You would normally not use the first form (unless you really, really know what you are doing.)

Thus the solution is to remove all the 'assign' keywords *if they are inside an always block*.

Outside an always you need the assign:

```
always @( * )
begin
  ...
  x = y ^ z;
end

assign write = valid & select;
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you should probably remove the `assign` keyword.

The `assign` keyword has two different meanings depending on context you do not show.

When used at the top level of a module, the `assign` keyword is a permanent process sensitive to RHS changes and assigns it to the LHS wire. The `assign` statement has equivalent functionality to the `always` block below

```
module mod;
 ...
 assign Awire = B + C;
 always @(B or C) begin
   Areg  = B + C; 
 end
endmodule
```

When used inside a procedural process, it is a temporary process that assigns the LHS variable every time the RHS changes. The two `always` blocks below have the same functionality

```
module top;
  ...
  always @(sel)
    begin
    if (sel)
      assign Areg = B;
    else
      assign Areg = C;
    end
 always @(sel or B or C) // @*
    begin
    if (sel)
      Areg = B;
    else
      Areg = C;
    end
endmodule
```

Unfortunately, almost all synthesis tools require you to write your code with a complete sensitivity list as in the latter always block. Thus this eliminates allowing the use of `assign` inside a procedural block.