# Trying to design a shift adder using Verilog, and I'm not able to fix this error

Tags: verilog, iverilog

I was implementing a 4-bit shift adder using Verilog, and I was facing an issue with the following code:

```
//shift register to store the two inputs a and b to be added
module shift(y, d, clk);
  input [3:0] d;
  input clk;
  output [3:0] y;
  reg [3:0] y;
  initial begin
    assign y=d;
  end

  always @(posedge clk)
    assign y= {1'b0, d[3:1]};
endmodule

//serial in parallel out register to store the 4 bit sum
module sipo(y, s, clk);
  input  s, clk;
  output [3:0] y;
  reg [3:0] y;
  always @(posedge clk)
    begin
      y={s,y[3:1]};
    end
endmodule

//1 bit full adder
module fa(s, cout, a, b, cin);
  input a, b, cin;
  output s, cout;
  assign {cout, s} = a + b + cin;
endmodule

//d flipflop to store the cout of each stage
module dff(q, d, clk);
  input d, clk;
  output q;
  reg q;
  initial begin
    q = 1'b0;
  end
  always @(posedge clk)
    begin
      q = d;
    end
endmodule

//main module serial adder//
module serial(sum, cout, a, b, clk);
  input [3:0] a, b;
  input clk;
  wire [3:0] x, z;
  output [3:0] sum; 
  output cout;
  wire s = 0;
  wire cin = 0;
  fa k(s, cout, x[0], z[0], cin);     //1 bit full adder
  dff q(cin, cout, clk);              //d flipflop to store the cout value after each 1 bit full adder operation
  sipo m(sum, s, clk);                //serial sum(s) converted to parallel output(4 bit sum)///
  shift g(x, a, clk);                 //shifts the input a
  shift h(z, b, clk);                 //shifts the input b
endmodule

module SATestBench;
  reg [3:0] a, b;
  reg clock;
  wire  cout;
  wire  [3:0] sum;
  serial  sa(sum, cout, a, b, clock);
  initial begin
    #5  clock = 1'b0;
    repeat(6)
    # 5 clock = ~clock;
  end
  initial begin
    #0  a = 4'b1000;  b=4'b0110;
    $monitor($time, " A = %b, B = %b, CarryOut = %b, Sum = %b.", sa.x, sa.z, cout, sum);
  end
endmodule
```

The error I was receiving was "vvp.tgt sorry: procedural continuous assignments are not yet fully supported. The RHS of this assignment will only be evaluated once, at the time the assignment statement is executed." I searched a bit online, and I found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54388004/when-i-compile-my-verilog-code-i-get-this-message-anybody-know-what-is-the-reas) that assign isn't allowed in always blocks.

Then I tried removing the assign block, and then the output for Sum/CarryOut was only "x"s. I'm not able to fix this, I've tried for many hours now. I've just started learning Verilog, so I apologise if this is a novice mistake.

Comment: The shift module is 4 bits in and 4 bits out.  Is this what you intended?  It seems like it should be 4 bits in and 1 bit out to support the use of a single bit FA?

Comment: @Mikef yes I tried with 4 bits in, 1 bit out but I wasn't able to understand how I'd "retain" the remaining bits inside of the shift module. The only solution I could think of was to output all 4 bits and pass the 0th bit to the adder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following snapshot of your exampe `assign` used inside procedural blocks is the *procedural continuous assignments* which your message complains about.

```
  initial begin
    assign y=d;
  end

  always @(posedge clk)
    assign y= {1'b0, d[3:1]};
```

This is a very special non-synthesizable statement seldom used if at all. You should avoid it.

Get rid of this keyword if it is used inside such a statemetn.

```
  initial begin
    y=d;
  end

  always @(posedge clk)
    y <= {1'b0, d[3:1]};
```

Now you have a multiple-driver problem. Variable **y** is driven from two different procedural blocks. You should change that and use a reset instead:

```
  always @(posedge clk) begin
     if (reset)
        y <= d;
     else
        y <= {1'b0, d[3:1]};
```

So, for that you should provide a reset.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me solve my problem. I don't understand the multiple driver problem though, from my understanding the initial block would run during instantiation of the module, so why doesn't this work as desired (assuming clock is first set high, some time after instantiation)?

Comment: Yes, *simulation* will work as you described. However, there can be *synthesis* issues and many tools will warn you of a potential problem here.